Lipschitz continuity of solution to parametric optimization problem
I have a question reagarding the Lipschitz continuity of the solution to a parametric convex optimization problem.
Setup:
Let $g_j : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be $\alpha$-strongly convex and continuously differentiable with $L$-Lipschitz continuous gradients $\nabla g_j$ for $j = 1,\dots,k$. Consider the parametric optimization problem
$$
z^*: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^n ,\, p \mapsto z^*(p) := \mathrm{argmin}_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n} \max_{j=1,\dots,k} g_j(z) - p_j.
$$
Question:
Does the following statement hold: The mapping $z^*$ is Lipschitz continuous.
Epilouge:
I have the strong feeling this has to hold but I am not able to show it. I was not able to perform a direct proof using only strong convexity of the function $g_j$. Using techniques from convex analysis and looking at the parametric prox $prox_{\max_{j=1,\dots,k} g_j(\cdot) - p_j}$ or the parametric convex subdifferential did not work out. I also tried to look at the parametric monotone inclusion
$$
0 \in F(z, p) := \partial \left ( g_j(\cdot) - p_j \right)(z) \subset \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
I started to look into implicit function theorems (, i.e., $0 \in F(z^*(p), p)$) for set-valued functions and more advanced stuff but I am not sure if this works out and this also seems a bit to complicated for the problem.
If you have any suggestions I would be very thankful!
